# how to save json data into csv using python

Tags: json, python-3.x

[I have json data  like this [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOIP2.png)]

I wanted to save the json into csv 
[the out put will be like this ,each tittle will be holding the information in that titile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63oZT.png)

Comment: What is your code so far?

Comment: I'm just a beginner in python programming so I'm not having any idea how to solve this problem

Comment: Please post a sample of your json data (not a picture) and the wished output fields you want

Comment: '{
  "basics": {
    "name": "John Doe",
    "label": "Programmer",
    "picture": "",
    "email": "john@gmail.com",
    "phone": "(912) 555-4321",
    "website": "http://johndoe.com",
    "summary": "A summary of John Doe...",
    "location": {
      "address": "2712 Broadway St",
      "postalCode": "CA 94115",
      "city": "San Francisco",
      "countryCode": "US",
      "region": "California"
    },
    "profiles": [{
      "network": "Twitter",
      "username": "john",
      "url": "http://twitter.com/john"
    }]
  }}

Comment: There is inconsistency in your output request, `basics` is not a value but a table. How could it fit in one single column?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this gets converted to a comment, but look at Pandas, it can probably do what you want ([Pandas json to csv](https://medium.com/@gis10kwo/converting-nested-json-data-to-csv-using-python-pandas-dc6eddc69175))